# Bash scripting - Iterating through "variable" variable names for a list of associative arrays

Tags: linux, bash, unix, associative-array

I've got a variable list of associative arrays that I want to iterate through and retrieve their key/value pairs.

I iterate through a single associative array by listing all its keys and getting the values, ie.

```
for key in "${!queue1[@]}" do
    echo "key : $key"
    echo "value : ${queue1[$key]}"
done
```

The tricky part is that the names of the associative arrays are variable variables, e.g. given count = 5, the associative arrays would be named queue1, queue2, queue3, queue4, queue5.

I'm trying to replace the sequence above based on a count, but so far every combination of parentheses and eval has not yielded much more then bad substitution errors. e.g below:

```
for count in {1,2,3,4,5} do
    for key in "${!queue${count}[@]}" do
        echo "key : $key"
        echo "value : ${queue${count}[$key]}"
    done
done
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The existing answers are largely out-of-date in the context of namevar support in bash 4.3 (and later).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty here stems from the fact that the syntax for indirect expansion (`${!nameref}`) clashes with the syntax for extracting keys from an associative arrays (`${!array[@]}`). We can have only one or the other, not both.

Wary as I am about using `eval`, I cannot see a way around using it to extract the keys of an indirectly referenced associative array:

```
keyref="queue${count}[@]"
for key in $(eval echo '${!'$keyref'}'); do ... ; done
```

You can however avoid `eval` and use indirect expansion when extracting a value from an array given the key. Do note that the `[key]` suffix must be part of the expansion:

```
valref="queue${count}[$key]"
echo ${!valref}
```

To put this in context:

```
for count in {1..5} ; do
    keyref="queue${count}[@]"
    for key in $(eval echo '${!'$keyref'}'); do
        valref="queue${count}[$key]"
        echo "key = $key"
        echo "value = ${!valref}"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work with the following script:

```
for count in {1..5} ; do
    for key in $(eval echo '${!q'$count'[@]}') ; do
        eval echo '${q'$count"[$key]}"
    done
done
```

Note it breaks if any key contained a space. If you want to deal with complex data structures, use a more powerful language like Perl.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work (but untested). The key is to treat the indexing
as the full name of a variable. (That is, the array `queue5` can be
treated as a sequence of variables named `queue5[this]`, `queue5[that]`, etc.)

```
for count in {1,2,3,4,5} do
    assoc="queue$count[@]"
    for key in "${!assoc}" do
        echo "key : $key"
        val="queue$count[$key]"
        echo "value : ${!val}"
    done
done
```

Comment: This seems to iterate through the values in the array (instead of the keys in the array). I guess you can dig out the key using the value with some work, but there might be a problem with non-unique values.

Comment: Indirect referencing works for accessing array values but not for keys. See my answer for details.