# How to get the keys and values of an associative array indirectly in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array, indirection

In Bash, given only a variable that contains the name of an associative array,

```
$ declare -A dict=([abc]=125 [def]=456)
$ dictvar="dict"
```

how can we retrieve the keys and values of the associative array?

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, to get keys of an associative array via indirection, given the name of the array in variable `dictvar` one can leverage `declare` or `local` ([original source](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#indirection)):

```
$ declare -a 'keys=("${!'"$dictvar"'[@]}")' # or 'local'
```

Then, to get the values

```
$ for key in ${keys[@]}; do
$     value_var="${dictvar}[$key]"
$     echo "$key = ${!value_var}"
$ done
```

An alternative using `eval` is suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13306800/435522).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839567/435522), in Bash 4.3+ this task is much easier to accomplish thanks to a new `declare -n` that can "resolve" a variable name into an actual variable.

Comment: I think the end curly brace is in the wrong place, should be:  `value_var="${dictvar[$key]}`