# How to get a last key of an associative array (dictionary)

Tags: bash

How I can have an access to the last key of the associative array in bash? In this example I need to have "lot" in the $last variable. I found a way described here: [How to get the keys and values of an associative array indirectly in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268669/how-to-get-the-keys-and-values-of-an-associative-array-indirectly-in-bash). But it doesn't work as expected in the example below and return this error:

```
./test.sh: line 9: keys2: ${!$addict[@]}: must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

Here are the contents of this test.sh:

```
declare -A addict=(
    ["foo"]="bar"
    ["few"]="baz"
    ["lot"]="pot"
)

index_last=$(( ${#addict[@]} - 1 ))
 eval 'declare -A keys2=(${!$addict[@]})'
last="${keys2[$index_last]}"

echo "$keys2"
echo "$index_last"
echo "$last"
```

Comment: The keys are unordered, so the concept of a "last key" doesn't really make sense. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29161323/2088135

Comment: Why are you using eval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Tom Fenech is absolutely right saying
*The keys are unordered, so the concept of a "last key" doesn't really make sense*, you can avoid the error by changing the line with `eval` to

```
keys2=( "${!addict[@]}" )
```

and see what you get. It may also be illuminating to look at `declare -p addict`. In order to get some key (first key that is *returned* from unordered keys list, not first key that was *declared*) you can do:

```
some_key="${keys2[0]}"
```

This way you could, for example, `unset A[$some_key]` and iterate over keys in such manner by picking first returned key each time.

Example:

```
$ declare -A A=( [a]=x [b]=y [c]=z )
$ echo "${!A[@]}"
c b a

$ keys=( "${!A[@]}" )
$ echo "${keys[0]}"
c
# you see that c was returned instead of a
# (on your computer order could be different)

$ unset A[$some_key]
$ echo "${!A[@]}"
b a

$ declare -p A
declare -A A=([b]="y" [a]="x" )
```

Further reading: [GNU Bash - Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).