# Bash: Iterate over variable names

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm writing a bash script to analyse some files. In a first iteration I create associative arrays with word counts for each category that is analysed. These categories are not known in advance so the names of these associative arrays are variable but all with the same prefix `count_$category`. The associative arrays have a word as key and its occurrence count in that category as value.

After all files are analysed, I have to summarise the results for each category. I can iterate over the variable names using `${count_*}` but how can I access the associative arrays behind those variable names? For each associative array (each `count_*` variable) I should iterate over the words and their counts.

I have already tried with indirect access like this but it doesn't work:

```
for categorycount in ${count_*} # categorycount now holds the name of the associative array variable for each category
do
    array=${!categorycount}
    for word in ${!array[@]}
    do
        echo "$word occurred ${array[$word]} times"
    done
done
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ? For instance, [edit] your code to populate 2 associative arrays and show us what you expect.

Comment: Solved: I finally found a SO question answering this problem
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13306800/5324593

Comment: Which version of bash? 4.3 has a new facility directly on-point.

Comment: BTW, [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) is directly on-point.

Comment: @ccarton, respectfully, the answer you linked to isn't appropriate for use with arrays, associative or otherwise.

Comment: @OKamers, using `eval` has serious security risks. It's possible to use it safely, but requires substantial command of the language, and using other facilities reduces the amount of effort needed to audit correctness. See [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Answer (score 3):

The modern (bash 4.3+) approach uses "namevars", a facility borrowed from ksh:

```
for _count_var in "${!count_@}"; do
    declare -n count=$_count_var                  # make count an alias for $_count_var
    for key in "${!count[@]}"; do                 # iterate over keys, via same
        echo "$key occurred ${count[$key]} times" # extract value, likewise
    done
    unset -n count                                # clear that alias
done
```

`declare -n count=$count_var` allows `"${count[foo]}"` to be used to look up item `foo` in the associative array named `count_var`; similarly, `count[foo]=bar` will assign to that same item. `unset -n count` then removes this mapping.

---

Prior to bash 4.3:

```
for _count_var in "${!count_@}"; do
  printf -v cmd '_count_keys=( "${!%q[@]}" )' "$_count_var" && eval "$cmd"
  for key in "${_count_keys[@]}"; do
    var="$_count_var[$key]"
    echo "$key occurred ${!var} times"
  done
done
```

**Note the use of `%q`, rather than substituting a variable name directly into a string, to generate the command to `eval`**. Even though in this case we're probably safe (because the set of possible variable names is restricted), following this practice reduces the amount of context that needs to be considered to determine whether an indirect expansion is secure.

---

In both cases, note that internal variables (`_count_var`, `_count_keys`, etc) use names that don't match the `count_*` pattern.